# What is the main purpose of writing this code?

Tags: php, html, twig

I am new to learning PHP. I was inspecting a theme file and in the layout section I found this code and it did not make sense to me. Since there were no comments, I could not find the purpose of this code on an e-commerce web page.Can you explain to me, the code snippet below?

```
<div class="row">
                    {% if site.route.group == "member" %}
                        <aside class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                            <div id="left-block">
                                {{ macro_global('leftBlocks') }}
                            </div>
                        </aside>
                    {% endif %}
                    <section class="{% if site.route.group == "member" %}col-md-8 col-lg-9{% else %}col-12{% endif %}">
                       {% block content %}{% endblock %}
                    </section>
                </div>
```

Comment: it is showing special content based on if the viewer is a registered user with member permissions

Answer (score 2):

From the Twig template you have pasted, it looks like this adds a side column for any sub-pages (`route.group == "member"`) that are displayed for members.
In the first section, it adds a 4/12 column-wide (standard grid=12 columns) side-bar for members.

In the bottom section (`<section class="{% if site.route.group == "member" %}col-md-8 col-lg-9{% else %}col-12{% endif %}">` it checks again if the side bar was added, and adjusts respectively the width of the block - either to 8 of 12 columns (in medium screen size), or 9/12 (in large screen size). If no sidebar was added earlier, it uses full width (12 of 12 columns).

For explanation of the 12-column grid system, see e.g. here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/